# Trying to delete steamapps from mounted SSD

Tags: mount, ssd, steam

I'm trying to delete steamapps from a 2tb ssd I mounted to ubuntu. Originally, I tried to move Steam from my boot drive to this second drive but to no avail.

After this I went through the process of deleting Steam so I could reinstall it, but steamapp is on the second drive and I cannot delete it: ***"steamapps" can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?.***

I click Delete and get this: ***Error while deleting. There was an error deleting the folder "steamapps". Error removing file/mnt/EFE9-F532/steamapps:Permission denied***. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try using `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, and didn't work. I formatted my 2tb ssd into the linux format (was using FAT initially) and steam can see it now. Should I delete this post?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob You can post an answer to your own question, and accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark beside it two days after you posted it.